# Are there nontrivial distributions completely determined by finite moments

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

We know that the Gaussian distribution is completely determined by its first 2 moments, i.e., $\mathbb{E}X,\mathbb{E}X^2$. Are there some well-studied examples of distributions determined by its first 3 moments, 4 moments, etc?  I think this is related to the Hamburger moment problem, but I'm more interested in specific examples rather than general proofs.

**EDIT**. More specifically, let $\theta = (\theta_1,...,\theta_d)\in \mathbb{R}^d$ for fixed $d$. Then I wish to find an injective map from $\theta\mapsto \mu_\theta$ into a subset $S_d$ of probability measures such that the inverse is equal to calculating the first $d$ moments. Indeed, if $d=2$, I can take the map $\theta\mapsto \mu_\theta$ to be defining Gaussian measures so that $S_{d=2}$ is just the collection of all Gaussian measures. What would $S_3, S_4$, etc be?

Comment: It could help if you exclude from [this list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions) those distributions you are not interested in. You are hopefully not asking us to google for you. It is also pretty unclear what a nontrivial distribution is to you.

Answer (score 1):

By 'distribution' you mean a family  of probabilities $\{\mu _{\theta}; \theta\in \Theta\}$ where $\Theta\subset R^d.$ More or less, the knowledge of $d$ moments gives $d$ equations liable to determine $\theta.$